# Print your system's logo

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

This is a throwback challenge. You will choose an old computer system and an old language created for that system.

## The challenge

Pick an old computer system that was made before the year 2000. In a programming language that was created to run on that system, print said system's logo.

Example systems, their languages, and their logos:

- [Atari ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_ST) - [GFA BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) - [Atari logo](http://www.matmoo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Atari.png)
- [Apple ][](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II) - [Applesoft BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applesoft_BASIC) - [Full logo](https://www.loveroms.com/assets/img/consoles/logos/apple-ii-gs.png) or [Apple only](http://www.logodesignlove.com/images/classic/apple-logo-rob-janoff-01.jpg)
- [IBM PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer) - IBM [`COMMAND.COM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM) or [BASIC-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BASIC#BASIC-80) - [IBM logo](https://mamedev.emulab.it/etabeta/fast/files/ibmpcjr/0000.png)

## The rules

- You may not download the logo/icon from the internet or read it from the filesystem.
- You must use graphics to print the logo - no ASCII art.
- The icon's size must be at least 20 pixels by 20 pixels.
- Your program will not take any input and will clear the screen, print the logo, and exit normally.
- If the logo includes colors, your program must print the logo in the same colors, unless your system does not have a color display.
- The computer must not shut down.
- [Your system must have a logo.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37729543#37729543)
- If the logo includes text (e.g. the `Apple ][` in the [Apple logo](https://www.loveroms.com/assets/img/consoles/logos/apple-ii-gs.png)), you only need to print the image part (e.g. the actual colored Apple).

## The winner

As with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the submission with the least bytes wins!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59513/discussion-between-riker-and-md-xf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [GFA BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) on Atari ST, 27 bytes

This is a manually edited source code in .LST format. It contains unprintable characters: `[SO]` and `[SI]` stand for ASCII characters #14 and #15 respectively. Both lines ends with `CR`.

```
DEFTEXT,,,32
TEXT0,28,"[SO][SI]"
```

This will draw a 28x26 Atari logo, which is part of the Atari ST system font.

[image: output]

Comment: I've cropped the output to the logo in the corner and Google's *Search by image* thinks it's a keyboard. While I'd consider this a flaw of the challenge spec rather than your answer, it still means that your answer doesn't comply with the current state of the rules.

Answer (score 3):

## [Applesoft BASIC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applesoft_BASIC) on the [Apple ][](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II), <s>365</s> 361 bytes

```
1GR:POKE-16302,0:I=0:O=15:P=1:Q=1:FORY=7TO47:I=I-1:IF(I<=0)THENI=7:READC:COLOR=C
2IF(Y<21)THENO=O-((21-Y)/12):GOTO4
3O=O+P-1:P=P*Q:Q=Q+0.002
4HLINO,39-O ATY:NEXT:DATA12,13,9,1,3,6:COLOR=0:HLIN16,22 AT7:HLIN18,20 AT8:HLIN16,22 AT47:HLIN18,20 AT46:VLIN14,34 AT32:VLIN15,33AT 31:VLIN16,32 AT30:VLIN18,30 AT29:VLIN22,26 AT28:COLOR=12:FORA=0TO3:VLINA,A+4 AT22-A:NEXT
```

Output and actual logo:

[image]      [image]

Comment: According to your own rules, this is invalid, as Google's *Search by image* fails to identify it as an Apple logo.

Comment: @Dennis Crud... yet it's clearly the logo. So I need a better validity check than that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't; fuzzy image comparison is hard. While a human observer might see what you're going for, the colors are wrong that the original logo doesn't consist of huge pixels.

Comment: @Dennis Well not necessarily a better image comparison than Google's Search by Image, that's more or less the best out there IME. I mean a better validity check as in a clear description of the boundaries between a valid submission and an invalid one - to prevent people from printing a big red box and saying  "It looks like the Apple logo without my glasses on" and complete-cheat submissions like that.

Comment: You won't get an *objective* validity criterion unless the test can be performed by a computer.